# How to use XMLPullParser on a local file

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am using the XMLPullParser to read a local XML file in the assets folder, the code for the tutorial is on the android developers website:

link: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html

code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

 public class SimpleXmlPullApp
  {

 public static void main (String args[])
     throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
 {
     XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
     factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
     XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

     xpp.setInput( new StringReader ( "<foo>Hello World!</foo>" ) );
     int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
     while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
      if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
          System.out.println("Start document");
      } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
          System.out.println("Start tag "+xpp.getName());
      } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
          System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
      } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
          System.out.println("Text "+xpp.getText());
      }
      eventType = xpp.next();
     }
     System.out.println("End document");
   }
 }`
```

I realise that the StringReader is what I have to replace, but what do I replace it with so that I can use the local file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the xml file is in the assets folder, it can be retrieved like this:

Use `context.getAssets().openXmlResourceParser(String filename)`.  It returns an `XmlResourceParser` which is an implementation of the `XmlPullParser` in their example.  If the file is in `assets/subfolder/file.xml`, the filename parameter would be `"subfolder/file.xml"`.

The other thing to consider is that you can put it in the XML folder under resources and retrieve it as R.xml.filename:

```
res/xml/filename.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<credits>
    <credit>one</credit>
    <credit>two</credit>
</credits>
```

In the Android Activity:

```
final XmlResourceParser parser = getContext().getResources().getXml(R.xml.filename);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying to the question I appreciate it! However, this has confused me slightly, If I use the XMLResourceParser object the error 'targetContext symbol is not recognised' Is there a newer version of the method? Also can I still use the Resource parser in the xpp.setinput or would I simply use the resource parser to query the xml file? Thanks again, jack

Comment: Try getContext().  Your example is from www.XmlPull.org documentation and is not android code. If you create a small android app, then it will have a context and a resources folder.

Comment: Yes, you would replace the first 4 lines of the example with the one line.