# How to convert an assets file to XML file

Tags: android, xml, parsing, android-assets

I wanna read an assets file which contains xml formed contents, but it's not a .xml file, so what should I do to read this file like a xml file so I can use some methods like getName, getAttributeName. Can I convert this file to an xml file, or should I use some method else? Any reply will be appreciated

Comment: maybe same as this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35759090/5183999

Comment: thanks, but not really, my file is not a xml file, it has different extension

Comment: If you have file encoding in proper xml format , your xml parser should able to parse .

Comment: @AnilRaavi But since I don't have a xml file, I can't even create a parser of XmlResourceParser, because it looks like it check if my resource type to see if I have a xml file. Even I do have a xml format file

Comment: your xml content is in some file ,right ?if so first read xml content string from file then  save that string as xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file is located in assets/dir/filename.txt, read like this:

```
InputStream in = this.getAssets().open("dire/filename.xml");
XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
parser.setInput(br);
```